# python - Inserting png picture into an email

Tags: python

I'm trying to do send an email with a picture in png format but somehow what i am trying below doesnt work (email is blank). Any idea how i could do it?

Later i will use a variable addressed to the png picture to define is the picture showed will be X or Y. For now I am just trying to display any picture, and i can't.

My code is (trying to to put in body "imaged"):

```
    from PIL import Image

    imaged = Image.open('down.png')
    imageu = Image.open('up.png')
    imageno = Image.open('nochanges.png')

    value = 0

    if value > 0 :
        activegraph = imageu
    elif value < 0:
         activegraph = imaged
    elif value == 0:
         activegraph = imageno


    subjecttext = "erewwerew"
    bodytext = """
            %s              
    """ % imaged


    import win32com.client
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = subjecttext
newMail.HTMLBody = bodytext
newMail.To = "test@test.com"
attachment1 = 'C:\\down.png'
attachment2 = 'C:\\up.png'
attachment3 = 'C:\\nochanges.png'
newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment2)
newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment3)
newMail.Send()
```

Comment: You can't just put a binary PNG in the email body like this. I have no experience with `win32com.client`, but you want to set it as an attachment.

Comment: actually i dont want it to be set is as attachment, I want it to be displayed along with the html body text.

Comment: Insert a url to the image hosted on your server and embed in the url in the html of your email

Comment: @Gonzalo You always need to set it as an attachment, and then reference it in the body text with `cid:`. Usually the MIME library provides an easy function for that. You could maybe include it with base64 CSS data urls, but I'm not sure what the email client support is for that.

Comment: @benbo Most email clients block external images for privacy reasons.

Comment: @benbo but i want to use it as a variable.. because sometimes X for instamce is a pic1 or sometimes can be pic2.

Comment: Fair enough. But maybe you want the recipient to be able to have external images blocked and only load them if he trusts the source of the email.

Comment: ok. just edited my code to send the the images as attachments, how can I call them now? thanks